# Javascript not iterating like expected

Tags: javascript

Can anyone tell me why my JS is not iterating through the loop and deleting items that are not "10" in the array?

As far as I understand it, it should be checking each item in the array and deleting any that are not 10, then returning the remaining items that are "10".

My current output is:  `[ <1 empty item>, 10, 50, 10 ]`

I've seen some answers that create a separate array and push items that are 10 to it and then return that, but why would my code not work?

```js
function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (obj.key.length === 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return [];
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.key.length; i++) {
      if (obj[key][i] !== 10) {
        delete obj[key][i];
      }
      return obj.key;
    }
  }
}

var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};
var output = getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `obj.key = obj.key.filter(n => n === 10)` ? Although I understand you're asking why yours doesn't work, not just asking for an alternative.

Comment: You're returning inside for loop as per your question you didn't intended to do that

Comment: Not only are you simply returning after the first iteration as @CodeManiac mentions, you're using `delete`, which won't re-index or update the array length - it only deletes the object property.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write like this to remove the correct items, you were returning inside the for loop so only the first item was being removed.

You can use the splice method instead of delete, because delete only deletes the reference and not the position of the array.

```js
function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (obj[key].length === 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return [];
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; i++) {
      if (obj[key][i] !== 10) {
        obj[key].splice(i, 1);
        i--;
      }
    }
    return obj[key];
  }
}

var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};
var output = getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key');
console.log(output);
```

Comment: @caffeinekitten this answer is incorrect.  If the given values [1000, 10, 50, 10] was changed to two consecutive non-10 values, it will return at least one of those non-10 numbers.  While the `splice` method is correct, there might be better answers that describe other issues with your code that don't produce incorrect results

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange design for a method.  It mutates *and* returns a result?  Generally, it's better to do one or the other (see [CQS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)).

Also, your original method is overly-coupled to an object structure.  It would be better to make it operate on an array only, leaving arbitrary object keys out of it.

Consider the following:

```js
function getElementsThatEqual10(array) {
  return array.filter(n => n == 10);
}

var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};
var output = getElementsThatEqual10(obj.key);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Though I get that there is clearly a cleaner way to write this, that isn't what I was asking. I am still learning how the code functions as is so yes, I am mutating and returning to view the results and what the code is doing.

Comment: Best of luck on your journey.  I hope it makes sense to you soon.

Answer (score 0):

The early return breaks out of the loop **after it finished deleting the first element only** (here simplified to simple array since the object isn't relevant):

```
let objKey = [1000, 10, 50, 10];

for (var i = 0; i < objKey.length; i++) {
  if (objKey[i] !== 10) {
    // Here it deletes 1000, the first element
    delete objKey[i];
  }
  // then it returns [undefined, 10, 50, 10]
  return objKey;
}
```

You could move `return` statement out of the loop to before `getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty` function ends.

Others have already suggested more elegant ways of doing this.

Comment: Though this didn't quite give me the answer it did get rid of an error .thanks

Answer (score 0):

#### What's wrong with your code

The primary issue is that you're doing a `return` from within the loop, meaning the function will exit completely when it hits that line during your very first iteration.

The second issue is more of a suggestion, but I wouldn't recommend using `delete`. While the object property is deleted, *`delete` does not update the array's `length` or or indexes*.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
delete array[0];
console.log(array.length);
```

Hypothetically you could chain a `.filter(n=>n)` to it and all would be well, but it's still an extra set of unnecessary iterations.

---

#### How to resolve it

The easiest way to filter items out of an array is by using the method of that name: [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Your updated function could look something like this instead.

```js
function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (Array.isArray(obj[key])                //Is it an array?
    return obj[key].filter(n => n === 10);   //Filter it for 10s
  else
    return [];
}

var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};

var output = getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key');
console.log(output);
```

Or, if you prefer brevity:

```js
const get10s = (obj, key) => Array.isArray(obj[key]) ? obj[key].filter(n => n === 10) : [];
var obj = { key: [1000, 10, 50, 10] };
console.log( get10s(obj, 'key') );
```

Answer (score 0):

**Well why your code was not working**

- Your `return` statement was inside for loop so it will return control as soon as your `if` condition fails.
- You're using `delete` which will delete the element but the index of other element will still be same as before. so you will get something like [undefined,10,undefined,10].

**So here's working mode of you code.**

```js
function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (obj.key.length === 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return [];
  } else {
    let temp = []
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.key.length; i++) {
      if (obj[key][i] == 10) {
        temp.push(obj[key][i])
      }
    }
    return temp;
  }
}

var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};
var output = getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key');
console.log(output);
```

**But i suggest using this one because it's clean and simple**

```js
function getElementsThatEqual10(array) {
  return array.filter(element => element === 10);
}

var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};
var output = getElementsThatEqual10(obj.key);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Alternative

If you are open to another method, you may try using `filter`, to parse the values you're after:

```js
const getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty = (obj, key) => obj[key].filter(v => v === 10)

var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};
var output = getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key');

console.log(output);
```

---

#### Your Code

Given your current method there are three issues:

1. you use `obj.key` in places that should probably be `obj[key]` since you are passing *key* in as an argument
2. `delete obj[key][i]` does not behave how you might expect, when operating on an array. As [@TinyGiant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4639281/tiny-giant) mentions, "it doesn't reorder the indices to remove the resulting empty slot."
3. `return obj.key` should be `return obj[key]` and it should be moved outside the loop because it is exiting the loop at the end of the first iteration

If you want to keep this method, I would recommend using `obj[key].splice(i,1)` as opposed to `delete`, which will alter the array.  However, because you are mutating the active array, you will also have to modify the `i` since the elements have shifted.  See below:

```js
function getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  if (obj[key].length === 0) {
    return [];
  } else if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    return [];
  } else {
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.key.length; i++) {
      if (obj[key][i] !== 10)
        obj[key].splice(i--,1)                    // remove value then alter i
    }
    return obj[key]                               // moved outside of the loop
  }
}

var obj = {
  key: [1000, 10, 50, 10]
};
var output = getElementsThatEqual10AtProperty(obj, 'key');
console.log(output);
```